# how to get the expected output in list format

Tags: python-3.x

below are 2 lst1 and lst2 and expected output is in output as below.

```
lst1 = ['q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']


lst2 =['1','2','3']
```

Output expected

```
 [['q','1'], ['r','2'], ['s','3'], ['t','1'],['u','2'],['v','3'],['w','1'],['x','2'],['y','3'], 
['z','1']]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple approach to this problem.

```
lst1 = ['q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
lst2 = ['1','2','3']

new_list = []

for x in range(len(lst1)):
    new_list.append([lst1[x], lst2[x % 3]])

print(new_list) # [['q', '1'], ['r', '2'], ['s', '3'], ['t', '1'], ['u', '2'], ['v', '3'], ['w', '1'], ['x', '2'], ['y', '3'], ['z', '1']]
```

You could also use list comprehension in this case, like so:-

```
new_list = [[lst1[x], lst2[x % 3]] for x in range(len(lst1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

```py
from itertools import cycle

lst1 = ['q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
lst2 =['1','2','3']

result = [[letter, number] for letter, number in zip(lst1, cycle(lst2))]
print(result)
```

Expected output:

```
[['q', '1'], ['r', '2'], ['s', '3'], ['t', '1'], ['u', '2'], ['v', '3'], ['w', '1'], ['x', '2'], ['y', '3'], ['z', '1']]
```

Another solution would be to additonally use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
result = list(map(list, zip(lst1, cycle(lst2))))
```

In case you wanna use tuples you could just do

```py
from itertools import cycle

lst1 = ['q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
lst2 =['1','2','3']


result = list(zip(lst1, cycle(lst2)))
print(result)
```

which would give you

```
[('q', '1'), ('r', '2'), ('s', '3'), ('t', '1'), ('u', '2'), ('v', '3'), ('w', '1'), ('x', '2'), ('y', '3'), ('z', '1')]
```